# How to test if foreign key is pointing to my object with JPARespository

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity A and B.  Entity A has a userid and expiration date.  B has a foreign key to A.  I want to delete expired rows of entity A, but I also want to exclude any rows that still have a foreign key pointing to them.

I'm using this to delete expired rows of A:

```
`void deleteByUserIdAndExpiryDateBefore(Long userId, Date expiryDate);`
```

Naturally, I get a foreign key constraint violation if I try to delete any entries for which there are B entries  is still pointing to A.  How can I fix my query to do this?  Not sure if there is a native JPARepository way to do it or I have to write my own query

Here's the entry in object A

```
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = B.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false)
    private B loginInfo;
```

The B entity does not have any reference to A

Answer (score 1):

You want to put `native query` with `inner join`. because `foreign-key` column of table `B` is referenced from table `A`. Your mapping is wrong you map `B` to `A` table but you want `A` to `B` table...

Here down is code:

**A**

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
private A a;
```

**B**

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
private B b;
```

You can not delete `Parent` table row without deleting `Child` table row. because `Parent` table `id` is mapped with `Child` table. Before delete `Child` table row who is relate to `primary key` of `Parent` table then delete `Parent` table row